# why node.next goes to the next node

Tags: java, linked-list

I am kind of new to programming and I am currently working on linked lists. I got this code somewhere online.

```
public class Node 
{
    Node next;
    int data;

    public Node(int data) 
    {
        this.data=data;
    }

    public class LinkedList
    {    
        Node head;
        public void delete(int data) 
        {    
            Node current=head;
            while (current.next!=null)
            { 
                if (current.next.data==data)
                {
                    current.next= current.next.next;
                }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

The thing which I don't understand is why `node.next` points to the next node? In the Node class next is a data type Node. There is no next method in the Node class but in the `LinkedList` class when `current.next` is called it suppose to refer to the next node.

Comment: @Jason If you don't know why then you don't know what is reference in java and it will be very hard to understand how the LL works. Node next is a reference to another Node object.

Comment: it is almost saying in one class int x;  and int y; in another class and using x.y to move over doesn't make sense

Comment: it points to the next node since the next node reference was (should have been) saved in `next`... but maybe you should ask who you got the code from ("somewhere online"?)

Comment: @Jason `head` is just an instance of Node. Because it is a Node, it has a member `next`. Because all Nodes have a `next` member of type Node, `head.next.next.next.next.next.next` is a perfectly legal statement (though you're 99% likely to get a NullPointerException if you ever use that in your code :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider thie code here every node i added in the main method is one object of the class Node and this class contains Node next which is a reference to the next node. For example the first node with value `22` contains a reference to the second node with value `2`. For example if you have only one node added the Node next will refer to null because there is no second node. In every node object the Node next reference gives you the next node. But i strongly suggest you to read what is reference in java because you miss a fundamental concepts here.

```
import java.util.Objects;

class LinkedList<T> {

    private class Node<E> {
        Node<E> next; 
        E val;

        Node(E val) {
            this.val = val;
        }
    }

    private Node<T> head;

    void add(T val) {
        Node<T> node = new Node<>(val);

        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            Node<T> p = head;

            while (p.next != null) {
                p = p.next;
            }

            p.next = node;
        }
    }

    void show() {
        if (head == null)
            return;

        Node<T> p = Objects.requireNonNull(head);

        while (p.next != null) {
            System.out.print(p.val + " ");
            p = p.next;
        }

        System.out.println(p.val);
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>();

        ll.add(22);
        ll.add(2);
        ll.add(4);
        ll.add(32);
        ll.add(3);
        ll.add(1);
        ll.add(44);

        ll.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a Node `n`. The class definition of Node contains a member variable declaration `Node next;` What this means is that every instance of class Node and its subclasses will have a member variable of type `Node` and name `next`. Therefore, there is no *method* named `next`. Instead, it's a *variable* being accessed. This is why the statement `current.next= current.next.next;` is legal - you *can't* write to the result of a function call (usually). However, you *can* write to a member variable (or a member variable of an instance of xyz class returned from a function call).

Comment: You can "write" to an array returned by a function call, but you shouldn't need to worry about that for LinkedLists :)